# Is it possible to change any of the HTML/URL returned from the_category()

Tags: functions, categories

I've found this is on of my theme files:

```
<?php the_category( ' ' ) ?>
```

Ideally I'd like to wrap the whole thing in a function and replace some of the URL's being output, but I don't seem to be able to affect the output at all:

```
<?php updateToPerfectURLs(the_category( ' ' )); ?>
```

Ultimately I want to change the URL's wordpress ic creating for my category pages. And it'd beyond what you can do with the category base setting....

Comment: May I know how you want the URL to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need this or what is your exact use case here, but, in short, [`the_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_category/) simply echos the returned value from [`get_the_category_list()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category_list/) which uses [`get_category_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_category_link/) which uses [`get_term_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/) to get the URL of the category page.

This is where you should look if you need to change the URL of link linking to the category page. In `get_term_link()`, there is a [`term_link` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/term_link/) that you can use to alter the URL returned for a specific term/category

```
return apply_filters( 'term_link', $termlink, $term, $taxonomy );
```

So, if you need to change the URL of term ID 1 for the `category` taxonomy, you can try something like the following piece of code (***NOTE:*** The code is untested)

```
add_filter( 'term_link', function ( $termlink, $term, $taxonomy )
{
    // Check if we have the correct term and taxonomy, if not, bail early
    if (    $term->term_id != 1 // Check if current term is 1 or not
         && $taxonomy != 'category' // Check if the current term is from the taxonomy category
    )
        return $termlink;

    // If we came to this point, we have the desired term and taxonomy, so lets alter the URL
    // Here should be the code to construct your new URL, you need to work on this
    $termlink = 'VALUE_OF_NEW_URL'; // This will be the new URL our term to link to its term page

    return $termlink;
}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: So do I just add the second code block to my functions.php file? I tried that and get: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '10' (T_LNUMBER)

Comment: Jip, it goes into functions.php. Sorry, I forgot a comma, have updated the code. Should be fine now

Comment: Wow worked a treat! Thank you so much for helping.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked :-). Enjoy